# Symfony2 asset resources from static domain or subdomain

Tags: php, caching, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I am trying to optimize my project to avoid send cookies with the static resources (i.e: images, scripts, stylesheets, etc). My approach is to create a static.my-domain.com domain to serve from there all the static resources without cookies.

**How can I load the resources from this domain using Symfony2 using asset?**

I am using Symfony 2.1 RC2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there's an [assets_base_urls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls) options that allows you to set assets domains.

Comment: Images are assets, load them with the asset() function

Comment: This answer has no information about how to serve Symfony assets from a subdomain. You have just provided an option under configuration. How to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

I added some twig globals to deal with this

```
# config.yml
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_version: 'dev'
        assets_version_format: "%%2$s/%%1$s"
    session:
        cookie_domain:        %session.cookie_domain%
twig:
    globals:
        assets_version: dev
        static_assets_base_url: %static_assets_base_url%
        static_images_base_url: %static_images_base_url%
        static_image: %static_images_base_url%/dev/ # I didn't know how to reference the assets_version, so this is the same value
        static_content: %static_images_base_url%/

# parameters.yml
parameters:
    session.cookie_domain: .myapp.dev
    static_assets_base_url: http://myapp-static.dev
    static_images_base_url: http://myapp-static.dev/path/to/web
```

- For versioned and compiled css/js etc I print `{{ static_assets_base_url ~ asset_url }}`.
- For versioned images etc I print `{{ static_image ~ 'bundles/mybundle/img/icon.jpg' }}`.
- For non-versioned images etc I print `{{ static_content ~ 'content/img/upload-123.jpg' }}`.

I don't remember exactly why I did this, but it was related to assetic bugs (what a surprise). It just can't handle paths correctly, like sometimes it doesn't add the version, or it does it wrongly.

It will be a pain if you have to modify the assets version manually, so you better have a deployment script ready to do this.

Oh and remember that Assetic won't dump the compiled assets in the specified directories, this is a known issue. So you have to add your own symlinks for these directories.

**EDIT**

The 'session.cookie_domain' parameter lets you use the same domain and avoid cookies, if your app is in a subdomain. If your app is not using a subdomain, you will have to use a separate domain for the static assets.